# Mun Numbers and Data in Ksp?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In Kerbal Space Program, even with using plugins that show data like I need, I can never find a conversion or something that will show the required fuel needed get the Delta V to reach a Mun encounter. Where can I find these values and if there is a conversion, where could I find it? And if it is known, how do you read the numbers on the Kerbal Engineering Redux plugin?

Comment: Doesn't setting your target as the Mun tell you these values in the UI?

Comment: Delta V depends greatly on your rocket and its mass.  Distance can be determined by targetting the moon, and angle by planning the maneuver.  There is no one answer to any of these.

Comment: @Frank Except you kind of just listed off the steps to take for one to obtain these numbers for their rocket? That seems like an answer to me.

Comment: @James The question isn't clear enough to figure out what he's asking about.  There needs to be more clarification, as it currently requires guessing.

Comment: @Frank I have not played KSP in a while.. but it seems like The Gamer just wants to know where to look in the UI to find that information?

Comment: @James There's no way to know that for sure.  I'd rather the question was clearer before I make an assumption to that effect.

Comment: @Frank Minimum delta-V between two orbits is completely independent of the rocket used.  That's why delta-V is used instead of other measures like fuel mass or burn times.

Comment: You should probably learn to use MechJeb. It gives you those numbers, and more.

Comment: Are you attaching a Kerbal Engineer part to your ship in the VAB?  That's how you can see Delta-V totals for your ship.  Using the Delta-V map, figure out how much Delta-V you need, multiply that by some margin of error, then build your ship accordingly.

Comment: There is no conversion for fuel to delta V, due to it differing based on how big your rocket is, the amount of possible thrust, and time to take to complete the maneuver.  That's why you get the Delta V value; that is a known quantity, and doesn't require specific knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

In the interface you can find is the altitude, orbital velocity, inclination and period of a planetary body, like Mün through the widgets on the centre right hand side in the map view.

Further, by setting any object as a target, you can use the map view markers for the ascending and descending nodes to figure out your relative inclination, by hovering over them.

Everything else you have to do the maths on for yourself, or using plugins to the game.

To answer your question specifically, though:

In order to best get to Mün, launch into an approximately equatorial orbit (off by no more than a degree, if you can swing it, although as much as 2 degrees might be workable).

After establishing a roughly circular orbit at anywhere from 70 to 120 km; wait for münrise. As Mün creeps over the horizon, hop into map view, point your ship prograde, and burn until you get an encounter.

Phase angles can be calculated using [this handy tool](http://ksp.olex.biz), and for Delta-V, I swear by [this handy map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYdUV.png):

[image: Kerbol system "subway map".]

Comment: This... this map is amazing. I've been curious about these for a while. I assume these are assuming a perfect transfer window?

Comment: @SaintWacko: I'm not sure about the context for these numbers. I assume they are "typical" numbers; indicating ∆V-numbers you should expect to need, not exact numbers.

Comment: I heard elsewhere on the Kerbal wiki that all these numbers are for *"perfect"* transfers. Real maneuvers will require a little bit more ∆V each, including correction burns.